# Exterior algebra and differential forms as equivalence classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

Let $(V,+,\cdot)$ be a vector space over field $K$ and $(T(V),+_T,\cdot_T,\times_T)$ be it's tensor algebra.
Where:
$$T(V)=\bigoplus\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}T^kV,\quad T(V)\ni v=(v_0,v_1,v_2,\dots)$$
(Where $v_0 \in K$, $v_1 \in V$, $v_2 \in V\otimes V$, $\dots $ and $v_i$=0 for cofinite number.)
And multiplication defined by:
$$\forall v,w \in T(V): (v \times_Tw)=(v_0\otimes w_0,v_1 \otimes w_0+v_0\otimes w_1,v_0\otimes w_2+v_2 \otimes v_0+v_1\otimes w_1,\dots)$$
The exterior algebra $\Lambda(V)=\frac{T(V)}{I}$ is a quotient algebra of $T(V)$ by the twosided ideal $I$ generated by the set:
$$ X=\{(0_R,0_V,x_i \otimes x_i,0_{V^\otimes 3},\dots)|x_i\in V\}\subset T(V)\\
I=\{\sum\limits_{i}((p_{0i},p_{1i},p_{2i},\dots)\times_T(0_R,0_V,x_i\otimes x_i,0_{V^\otimes 3},\dots)\times_T(s_{0i},s_{1i},s_{2i},\dots))|x_i \in V;\\p,s\in T(V)\}$$
Congruence generated by $I$: $\forall a,b \in T(V): a\sim b:\Leftrightarrow (a-b)\in I$
So then: $\Lambda(V)=\{[v]_\sim :v\in T(V)\}=\{\{w \in T(V)|v-w\in I\}|v\in(T)\}$
And :
$$\wedge:\Lambda(V)\times \Lambda(V) \to \Lambda(V) \\ \forall \alpha,\beta\in \Lambda(V): \alpha \wedge \beta = [a]_\sim\wedge [b]_\sim=[(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots)]_\sim \wedge [(b_0,b_1,b_2,\dots)]_\sim := [a\times_T b]_\sim$$
Then we define k-th exterior power $\Lambda^k(V)$ as vector subspace, such that:
$$\Lambda(V)\supseteq\Lambda^k(V):=span(X)\\
X:=\{[(0,x_1,0,\dots)]_\sim\wedge \dots \wedge[(0,x_k,0,\dots)]_\sim|x_i \in V\}$$
Now if we choose $V=T^*_p M$, for point $p$ of some smooth manifold $M$. Then smooth differential $k$-forms at point $p$ are the elements of $\Lambda^k(T^*_pM)$

**Question:** It's often said that differential forms at point are some sort of tensors, but how can we ***formally*** speak of them that way if in fact they are just linear combinations of equivalence classes of some sequences from tensor algebra?

Comment: there is a natural injective map $\bigwedge V \to TV$ defined by $v_1\wedge\dots\wedge v_k\mapsto \sum_\sigma (\operatorname{sgn}\sigma)v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes\dots \otimes v_{\sigma(n)}$; this is what is used to see differential forms as tensors. In fact, one often defines $k$-forms as skew-symmetric $k$-linear maps, which makes them to tensors (sections of ${T^*}^{\otimes k}M$ are $k$-linear maps).

Comment: @user8268 How do you define that injection if elements of $\Lambda (V)$ are equivalence classes and elements of $T(V)$ are sequences?

Comment: what I wrote is an injection $\bigwedge^k V\to T^k V$

Answer (score 0):

Viewing the exterior power this way can be very cumbersome. Tensors in $V^{\otimes n}$ are best viewed via their universal property: any multilinear map $f: V^n \to U$ uniquely factors through the tensor product, and so specifying where a *linear* map sends a tensor $v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n$ is the same as specifying where a *bilinear* map sends the tuple $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$. Put another way: if all you can work with are linear maps, but you need to express a bilinear map out of $V^n$, use a linear map out of $V^{\otimes n}$ instead.

Tensors in an exterior power are analogous. Call a multilinear map $f: V^n \to V$ *alternating* if $f(v_1, \ldots, v_n) = 0$ whenever any $v_i = v_j$ for $i \neq j$. The $n$th exterior power $\bigwedge^n V$ has the property that any multilinear alternating map $f: V^n \to U$ uniquely factors through $\bigwedge^n V$, and therefore may be viewed as a kind of "alternating tensor".

The notes [here](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/notes/28.pdf) define the exterior power as a quotient of $V^{\otimes n}$ by a certain ideal, and then quickly show the universal property, and the rest of the notes just use this universal property. I think understanding these notes will mostly answer your question.